# how to add Html5 carousel in magento?

Tags: javascript, xml, html, magento, carousel

I have made a carrousel whit jquery, js, xml,html5 but I want to set it on a page in magento but where do I need to place my js files and xml file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your all js at main js folder

```
magento_application\js\yourfolder // add all js related to your carousel
```

Add css files for carousel.css at

```
magento_application\skin\frontend\base\default\css\yourfolder
```

add carousel.css at above folder

Add your xml to layout base or your custom package or custom theme

like below

```
magento_application\app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\yourfolder\yourmodule.xml
```

Add all js and css in your head part of custom page or layout.xml to call in every page

For custom page as below you can add

Brands

```
    <reference name="head">                 
        <action method="addJs"><script>yourfolder/carousel.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>yourfolder/os.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>yourfolder/application.js</script></action>  
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/inic/carousel.css</stylesheet></action>
     </reference>
```

hope this will sure help you.